# Mysql - can't select records which exist in table A and don't exist in tables B,C,D

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to select records which exist in **users** table but don't exist in tables **groups_members, groups_members_unapproved** and **groups_invitations**.

**$_POST['msg_id']** contains multiple user IDs and I don't know how to use **implode** statement in 3 subqueries, so I replaced it with ??? - question marks.

Thanks.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users
WHERE id IN (". implode(', ', $_POST['msg_id']).")
AND id NOT IN (SELECT memberid FROM groups_members where memberid='???' and groupid='$cid')
AND id NOT IN (SELECT memberid FROM groups_members_unapproved where memberid='???' and groupid='$cid')
AND id NOT IN (SELECT invited FROM groups_invitations where invited = '???' and groupid='$cid')",$gb1) or die('Error');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are likely looking to do is a LEFT OUTER JOIN like this

```
SELECT id FROM users AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN groups_members AS gm ON u.id = gm.memberid
LEFT OUTER JOIN groups_members_unapproved AS gmu ON u.id = gmu.memberid
LEFT OUTER JOIN groups_invitations AS gi ON u.id = gi.invited
WHERE
id IN (<your implode here>)
AND gm.memberid IS NULL
AND gmu.memberid IS NULL
AND gi.invited IS NULL
AND gm.groupid <> <your group id>
AND gmu.groupid <> <your group id>
AND gi.groupid <> <your group id>
```

The thought here being that the outer join will return records across all joined tables even when there are not matching id's, but that the `* IS NULL` lines in the where clause will limit those records to only the cases where there are not matching member id's between the user table and any of the other tables.

I wasn't quite sure what value the `groupid` was bringing in your query. I would think that if you are concerned with identifying records at the user level that it would be an unnecessary field to filter on.

This should be a more efficient query than using subselects, so long as all your ID fields are indexed.  Of course if this is a query which you expect to execute frequently, you may want to consider a schema change to get an even more optimized query.

Comment: You'll want to replace the `= NULL` with `IS NULL`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes. Corrected.

Comment: My question was not accurate. "groupid" is very important here because I need to select records which don't exist in 3 tables - groups_members, groups_members_unapproved, groups_invitations with the same "$groupid". They query should select records even if they exist in 3 tables but have a different groupid.

Comment: @user1692255 I have update the answer to reflect filtering out records with the provided group id.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to just leave the `???` out in the subqueries since they're not needed there;

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN (...)
AND id NOT IN 
  (SELECT memberid FROM groups_members WHERE groupid='$cid')
AND id NOT IN 
  (SELECT memberid FROM groups_members_unapproved WHERE groupid='$cid')
AND id NOT IN 
  (SELECT invited FROM groups_invitations WHERE groupid='$cid')
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74ebe/1).